# Есть массив из ссылок, как из добавить есть класс активности, если у нее его нет, а если есть, то наоборот убрать?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из ссылок, нужно чтобы при нажатии на ссылку у нее появлялся класс активности, при нажатии на другую ссылку, у прошлой пропадал класс активности, а у той которую нажал, появлялся (Это все я смог сделать), но если еще раз нажать на активную кнопку, нужно чтобы класс активности убирался.
Вот код(что может быть не так?):

```
headerLink.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        
        if (e.target.className == 'active__two__link') {
            e.target.classList.remove('active__two__link');
        } else {
            headerLink.forEach(elem => {
                elem.classList.remove('active__two__link');
            });
            e.target.classList.add('active__two__link');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В условии вместо
(e.target.className == 'active__two__link')
я написал
(e.target.classList.contains('active__two__link'))
и все заработало